# Hibernate unwanted / unexpected delete statement after update in @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, cascade

I will give some general information about my webapp (I will mention only the tables that have the issue for now). So, I have 3 tables Trainer, Event and Event-Trainer .

```
CREATE TABLE `Event` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Duration` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Days` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `Price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `PlaceLimit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '(No notes)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `CategoryID_idx` (`CategoryID`),
  CONSTRAINT `CategoryID` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `Category` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE `Trainer` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Picture` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) 
CREATE TABLE `Event-Trainer` (
  `EventID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TrainerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EventID`,`TrainerID`),
  KEY `FK_TrainerID` (`TrainerID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EventID_2` FOREIGN KEY (`EventID`) REFERENCES `Event` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_TrainerID_2` FOREIGN KEY (`TrainerID`) REFERENCES `Trainer` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

These are the entities classes

```
//Event.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Event", schema = "business-club")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    ...    

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CategoryID")
    private Category category;



    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
            , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "`Event-Trainer`",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EventID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TrainerID")
    )
    private List<Trainer> trainers;
...
}

//Trainer.java
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Trainer", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"FirstName","LastName","Email"})})
public class Trainer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name="`Event-Trainer`",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TrainerID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name="EventID")
    )
    private List<Event> events;
```

Now let's get to the problem, I have been experiencing a weird behavior with Hibernate which is after I update a Trainer it "Unexpectedly" deletes the records related to that trainer in the Event-Trainer table here's hibernate's log after I update a trainer

```
Hibernate: update Trainer set City=?, Email=?, FirstName=?, LastName=?, Phone=?, Picture=?  where ID=?
Hibernate: delete from `Event-Trainer` where TrainerID=?
```

I tried changing the cascading types in both entities and it didn't work, I changed the fetch type to LAZY and I got an exception when updating (it would be much appreciated if someone explains this to me though I don't think it's a big deal, at least for now)

I will post more information if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping of the many to many relationship is not correct. You should make one side master and the other slave by using mappedBy attribute in @ManyToMany.

Comment: I didn't know what side should be the master, can you further explain to me? And how can I use the mappedBy attribute (I would be perfect if you give me an existing example similar to mine) Thanks

Comment: See the section "2.10.4 Bidirectional ManyToMany  Relationships" in the JPA 2.1 JSR http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-eval-spec/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think CascadeType.DETACH over table 'Event-Trainer' is causing the issue.
Are you able to see your updated values in 'Trainer' table ?

Comment: The update are working fine in the Trainer table, I tried to remove that "CascadeType.DETACH " but it didn't have any changes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mohamed Gara, here's the solution to my problem
I changed

```
//Trainer Entity
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name="`Event-Trainer`",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TrainerID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name="EventID")
    )
    private List<Event> events;
```

To

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "trainers",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Event> events;
```

And

```
//Event Entity
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
            , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "`Event-Trainer`",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EventID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TrainerID")
    )
    private List<Trainer> trainers;
```

To

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Trainer> trainers;
```

I also had to change the name of my table Event-Trainer to `Event_Trainer` and the name of the primary keys from EventID,TrainerID to events_ID, trainers_ID respectively. (I did this after some exceptions that were thrown)

**EDIT 1**

I got an exception when deleting a trainer assigned to an event so I changed the ON DELETE and ON UPDATE for both foreign keys from NO ACTION to CASCADE and specified the cascade types in the @ManyToMany annotation in both entities

```
@ManyToMany( ... cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
```